# Can't invoke functions in cordova - visual studio

Tags: cordova, typescript, cordova-3, visual-studio-cordova

I am creating first cordova app via visual studio cordova tools.
I am using windows 7 and VS Community (if that is important) and ripple emulator.
Problem is that I have code like this: `<button onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Click Me</button>` and my function is defined `in index.ts`.
But I am getting error `Exception: showAlert is not defined` when click on button.
What am I missing here?
This is compelte code:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Cordova01</title>

    <!-- Cordova01 references -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, your application is ready!</p>
    <p><strong>Hello, from Cordova :)</strong></p>
    <button onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Click Me</button>
    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>    
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.ts

```
module Cordova01 {
    "use strict";

    export module Application {
        export function initialize() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
            document.addEventListener('pause', onPause, false);
            document.addEventListener('resume', onResume, false);

            // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.

        }

        function showAlert() {
            navigator.notification.alert(
                "This is simple message!",  // message
                null,       // callback
                "Alert View Title", // title
                'OK'        // buttonName
                );    
        }

        function onPause() {
            // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
        }

        function onResume() {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
        }

    }

    window.onload = function () {
        Application.initialize();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you should change the `showAlert` function to `export function showAlert()`
And in the html change it too `<button onclick="Cordova01.Application.showAlert(); return false;">Click Me</button>`

In your case it couldn't find the showAlert function because it is in a module. Another way is to move the `showAlert` function out of the module for testing, that should work too!

See fiddle for an example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5n90w9u/1/)